# Determine $(n, p)$ such that $(p - 1)^n + 1$ is divisible by $n^{p - 1}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Determine all pairs $(n, p)$ of positive integers such that $p$ is a prime, $n$ does not exceed $2p$, and $(p - 1)^n + 1$ is divisible by $n^{p - 1}$.

IMO 1999/4

Answer (score 0):

For $n = 1$ any $p$ is divisible by $1$ so $(1, p)$ is a solution for any prime $p$.

Let $n > 1$. Since for $p = 2$ the only solution is $(2, 2)$, assume $p$ odd. Assume, also, $p \not | n$. Denote $n = pk + r$ for $0 \leqslant k \leqslant 1$ and $0 < r < p$. We have $$n^{p - 1} = (pk + r)^{p - 1} \equiv r^{p - 1} \pmod {p}.$$ Since $(r, p) = 1$, by Euler's Theorem we have $n^{p - 1} \equiv r^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod {p}$. Also, $n$ cannot be even, since, otherwise, $(p - 1)^n + 1$ would be odd but $n^{p - 1}$ even. Hence, $n$ is odd. Then, $$(p - 1)^n + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod {p},$$ by which we deduce that there exists an odd integer $s$ such that $(p - 1)^{pk + r} + 1 = ps(pk + r)^{p - 1}$. We then write $$\sum_{i = 0}^{pk + r - 1} {pk + r \choose i + 1} (-p)^i = s \sum_{i = 0}^{p - 1} {p - 1 \choose i} (pk)^i r^{p - 1 - i},$$ which is impossible, since $k$ is $0$ or $1$. Hence $p | n$.

Since $n \leqslant 2p$, we have $n = p$ or $n = 2p$. Let $n = p$. Then for some positive integer $s$ we have $$(p - 1)^p + 1 = sp^{p - 1}.$$ Since both $(p - 1)^p + 1$ and $p^{p - 1}$, we deduce that $s$ is odd. For $p > 3$ this is impossible, since RHS would divide $p^3$ but LHS would not; therefore, $p = 3$ and indeed $(3, 3)$ is a solution. Finally, assume $n = 2p$. Since $n^{p - 1} = (2p)^{p - 1}$ divides $p$ but $(p - 1)^n + 1 = (p - 1)^{2p} + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod {p}$ does not, there is no solution in this case.

The solutions are $(n, p) = (1, p), (2, 2), (3, 3)$.

"Notes on Olympiad Problems", Nima Bavari, Tehran, 2006.